# Como hacer un 'JOIN' de 2 hojas para guardar los datos en una tercera

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Ando con Google Sheets y estoy tratando de que en una 3ra hoja guardar los datos echos de un posible 'join' entre 2 hojas en el mismo documento, paso a dar mas información

---

**USUARIOS** --> DNI (clave), NOMBRE, APELLIDO, TELÉFONO, MODALIDAD, ESTADO, REGISTRO

**PAGOS** --> DNI (clave), NOMBRE, APELLIDO, MODALIDAD, MONTO, MÉTODO, FECHA

**DEUDORES** --> DNI, NOMBRE, APELLIDO, MODALIDAD, ULTIMO PAGO

---

En **USUARIOS** se cargan los datos de todos los usuarios

En **PAGOS**, se agrega el DNI del usuario en la columna correcta y desde la tabla de USUARIOS se trae el NOMBRE y APELLIDO

Por ultimo, en **DEUDORES**, busco traer todos los usuarios que en el ultimo mes no pagaron la mensualidad (se encuentra en PAGOS) y son usuarios activos (se encuentra en USUARIOS) haciendo un 'join' de ambas tablas

Pobre varias formas pero no doy con la solución, soy nuevo en esto y todo lo que logre fue investigando, pero esto me supera, para acotar un poco mas de info, en ambas hojas los datos arrancan desde **B4:H**

---

Dejo como referencia una de las consultas que estuve probando que daba error

```
=QUERY({USUARIOS!B4:H; PAGOS!B4:H}; "SELECT * WHERE COL1 = COL9"; 0)
```

El problema es que no existe col9, llega hasta la 8.

Muchas Gracias!